# Inserting Data from Asp.net Webpage into local SQL express database

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

very new to coding, i'm basically trying to create a asp website that will display data in a grid, which i got working fine ( simple enough ) however i want to be able to add it

i've got a default.aspx where my data is presented and an Add.aspx which is my insert page.

i've got 4 text boxes which i use to type data into and on push of a button it will insert the data into the sql express db i have running,

im running , 1 DB with 1 table, so you can understand how simple my little project is.

i ran debugs and i got no issues:

code for default.aspx

```
</title>
</head>
<body>
    <strong style="border-style: ridge">:: Server List Details Page ::</strong>
<p></p>


    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>

            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowSorting="True">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ServerName" HeaderText="ServerName" 
                        SortExpression="ServerName" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" HeaderText="IPAddress" 
                        SortExpression="IPAddress" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                        SortExpression="Description" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Location" HeaderText="Location" 
                        SortExpression="Location" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button ID="Add" runat="server" Text="Add Device" OnClick="Add_click" OnClientClick="window.open('add.aspx', 'add');"/>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [ServerName], [IPAddress], [Description], [Location] FROM [Table1]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
```

code for ADD.aspx

```
    <title></title>
    </head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <strong>:: Add Device Details ::
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    </strong>

    Server Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    IP Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Description:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    Location:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Generate_Data" runat="server" Text="Generate Data" 
        onclick="Generate_Data_Click" PostBackUrl="~/Default.aspx" />
    </form>





</body>
</html>
```

Code for Button to submit information:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Table_to_DB
{
    public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Generate_Data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source= 172.17.10.89; initial catalog=database1");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO database1 (" + " servername, ipaddress, description, Location " + ") VALUES (" + " @TextBox1.text, @TextBox2.text, @TextBox3.text, @TextBox4.text" + ")", cn);

            cn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cn.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

The problem im having is that when i input my data and submit it, nothing errors and no data ends up in the table.

please help, most of this code i got off the net and im still learning.

Answer (score 2):

Your command text is wrong. Passing a parameter to a SqlCommand should be this

```
string cmdText = "INSERT INTO table1 (servername, ipaddress, description, Location) " + 
                 "VALUES (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4)";
string conString = "Data Source= 172.17.10.89; initial catalog=database1";

using(SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, cn))
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",TextBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",TextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4",TextBox4.Text);
    int recordsAdded = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

You can't pass directly the property text of your textboxes into the command text.
Here you set some placeholders (I have called then generically @p1, etc, but you could change to a more precise name of your like) and then you prepare the Parameters collection of the SqlCommand setting for every placeholder the value that you want to store in the database.
Also I reccomend to give more meaningful names also to your textboxes.

**And keep using parameters ALWAYS. Do not use string concatenation. It might seem faster, but it is the road to hell**

Comment: +5 definitely, for the last sentence in bold.

Comment: still no luck, it seems like it doesnt create the connection to the db at all... no debug errors and also after the @p4)"; the simi-colon errors im assuming there should be a ) after the "

was i meant to edit any of my code to accomodate for those p1,p2,p3,p4

Comment: Yes, you are right, forgot the closing braces of the SqlCommand creation and the connection. If you have a problem in connecting to the server an exception should be raised. Do you have any try/catch in the code calling this method? If yes, do not swallow the exception and try to write the error message received, if not try to add something here to print the message. Also added a counter of the records inserted. It should be 1

Comment: Just noticed a possible bug. Your database in the connection string is called `database1`, but in your insert command you use that name as the name of a table `INSERT INTO <tablename> ....` Do you have a table named `database1`?

Comment: the database = database1 and table = table1

this is still test phase, as im learning

Comment: So the INSERT INTO should be changed accordingly

Comment: Data Source = Database1
insert into = Database1
or
Data source = Table1
Insert into = Table1

sorry for dumb questions

tried both combinations and still no luck :O

Comment: No `Data Source=XXXX` or `Server=XXXX` should be or the name of your host where you have installed the database or the IP address of the same host. See [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/)

Comment: not sure if this could be the problem but i just tried telneting my system on port 1433 to see if its serving correctly but no luck but i might be looking in the wrong place here... any thoughts ?

Comment: Are you able to debug this code?. Step by step. When you call cn.Open it should raise an exception. The Exception.Message property will contain useful info

Comment: to be honest im not sure how to debug correctly, i have the output list below and the error list i look at and when i run it, it runs in the debug mode at the top. is there anynother way i should go about this

Comment: In Visual Studio. Right click the Open line, select BreakPoint from the menu and insert a BreakPoint. Run the program with F5 and when the execution stops at the breakpoint press F10 to execute one step. Look if you get an exception and what are its properties